# ttyusb/uart sends 'USB' during transfer

Tags: go, usb, uart, tty

I am using Go for a project and am transmitting data to an embedded device via the serial port (ttyusb). During fast and "large" transfers I've noticed that the transmitted data did not match the values I'd wanted to send.

I've tried various available libraries, in the end they all read and write using syscalls. So I've attached a Logic Analyzer to see what's going on.

Then I noticed that the data mismatch in the output had a clear pattern: Instead of sending my data the serial port would interleave my data with the following values:

`0x55, 0x53, 0x42, 0x53, 0x70, 0x02`

Followed by zeros (`0x00`). In total 22 Bytes. The total number of bytes transmitted via the serial line did match the number of bytes I wanted to write > so essentially my data was masked with these 22 Byte-Blocks. The weird thing is that I can translate those bytes to ASCII

`0x55, 0x53, 0x42, 0x53, 0x70 = "USBSp"`

Now my **Question** is: Can't I send arbitrary data (HEX values) over the serial port or are there some control characters that I should be aware of that would make the serial port send out Identity information or the like?

**[EDIT]: Additional Information:**

- Host is MacOS running Go v1.10; tried with `go.bug.st/serial.v1` and `github.com/tarm/serial`, various communication settings (bitrate etc.)
- Target is [nRF52840 preview development kit](https://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/Products/nRF52840-Preview-DK), using Nordic nRF5 SDK v12.3.0_d7731ad (not the newest, I know, but the only one supporting other boards too). Using `app_uart_x` API

Comment: I'm seeing exactly the same issue! nRF52840 DK (not the preview one.) Except in my case it's "USBSP" with uppercase P.

When sending large messages, random chunks get overwritten with "USBSP\0\0\..".

Any help would be extremely appreciated!

Comment: I had this problem communicating from the PC to the DK, I didn't have this problem the other way around. What I ended up doing was adding wait-states on the PC side, so I've simply added a tiny delay of < 1 ms after sending a chunk of data (don't remember the size though). I suggest playing around with those parameters (chunk size and timeout) and think about flushing the serial every now and then.

Comment: also: this might help https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/178839/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-bytes-that-can-be-sent-through-usb-to-serial-com-p/178858 try reducing your packet size to 64 bit, little timeout inbetween

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to configure the serial port. the settings for both devices for baud rate, start/stop bits, ... have to match. then there are libraries in go like https://github.com/jacobsa/go-serial that enable standard serial port communication with that you can also use any hex values.

i can not say why the `USBSp` is sent because you did not post any code and gave no information what libraries you use. very likely this is not generated by the kernel module and instead by higher layer software because the kernel module used is `usb-serial` and `USBSp` does not appear in the source code :

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.0/source/drivers/usb/serial/usb-serial.c

also not in kernel module `ftdi-sio` ( if you use ftdi chip )

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.0/source/drivers/usb/serial/ftdi_sio.c

and also not in https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.3/source/drivers/usb/core/urb.c

Comment: the communication settings are identical (triple-checked that), normal communication works without problems. couldn't think of a usable snipped since it is literally serial.write on one side and serial.read on the other. what might be the issue is the USB-to-serial conversion on the board: it is integrated in the silicon, which is an engineering sample ... still investigating. thanks for the input on the linux distros

Comment: to close this: we've switched MCU so it really seems that it was a problem with the USB of the nRF, didn't have this problem with the new MCU and could remove all workarounds.